# Use same GA Account Number to send ecommerce tracking from 2 carts to same GA Account?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

Client on same shopping cart platform has different carts and we would like to send ecommerce tracking data to a single Google Analytics Account from both carts. Can we simply use the same Google Analytics Account Number in each instance? Can ecommerce tracking be rolled up in this way?

Comment: Yes you can do this but you are better off creating a separate profile under your main analytics account for the second site so that you can at least segment the analytics and see where traffic is coming from one each domain. If the layout and design is different on each domain you can run tests with website optimizer and setup event tracking to monitor clicks. I don't use the same GA tracking code on all my sites I create new profiles, you can always combine the e-commerce data transactions revenue etc by exporting to excel. Or integrate with oAuth and have a script do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You don't need two accounts.

Later if you want to see transactions that happened only on one site you could create an advanced segment for each domain and analyze them separately.

Another idea is to put the cart domain inside the Affiliation field of the transaction. This field is usually left blank but you can use it to store anything.